# Why are there no dropout layers in inception net?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, dropout

I recently was implementing the InceptionNet and came across the scenario where the dropout layer was not implemented in the network at all in the early or mid stages. Any particular reason for this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a software development question. Pure machine learning questions are more likely to be suitable for [stats.se] or [datascience.se]

Answer (score 0):

You can see this paper posted model:[image]

Comment: I don't mean it like that. I wanted to ask why is there no dropout layer after the inception blocks?

Comment: The Batch Normalization method is a very efficient regularization method, which speeds up the training of large convolutional networks by many times and improves the classification accuracy after convergence, thus reducing or eliminating Dropout and simplifying the network structure.

Answer (score 0):

It actually has a slight regularization effect which is similar to dropout.
Think like that we are choosing every node with a certain possibility for that
layer so we creating our NN architecture with a possibilities. Similar
situation is valid also in here but this time we apply the all possibilities.
Hence, inception network helps to prevent over fitting the parameters so that
learning is happening for more deeper understanding please check out the
original paper but that is just an observation not a prove.